# Formatar número na hora do echo com 'k', 'kk', e assim em adiante

Tags: php

Em vários lugar da internet é possível visualizar formatações de números como "150k", "1kk". A maioria das pessoas sabe que 150k corresponde a 150.000 e 1kk corresponde a 1.000.000.

EXEMPLO:
[image]

Isso seria útil pois as vezes mexo com grandes números, o que esteticamente é ruim, pois às vezes ultrapassa limites! Com esse tipo de formatação o número sempre estaria resumido.

Gostaria que essa formatação começasse a partir do primeiro "1.000" o que logo seria "1k", gostaria também que o número sempre fosse arredondado pra cima e não para baixo.

Exemplos de formatação:

```
10             =  10
100            =  100
999            =  999

1.000          =  1k
1.499          =  1k
1.501          =  2k
10.000         =  10k
100.000        =  100k

1.000.000      =  1kk
10.000.000     =  10kk
100.000.000    =  100kk

1.000.000.000  =  10kkk
```

Gostaria então de saber como se faz isso no momento do `echo`.

Comment: O correto não seria `1K`, `1M` e `1G`?

Comment: @renan ambas as formas seriam uteis, é porque to mais acostumado só com os "k" mesmo!

Comment: 1k = 1000 1000k = 1.000.00 Não existe "kk".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aqui está a sua função:

```php
function reduz_numero($n) {
    if ($n < 0) return "-" . reduz_numero(-$n);
    $k = "";
    while (round($n) >= 1000) {
        $k = $k . "k";
        $n = $n / 1000;
    }
    return round($n) . $k;
}
```

Alguns testes com ela, usando `echo`:

```
echo "         5->" . reduz_numero(         5) . "\n"; // Mostra "5"
echo "       999->" . reduz_numero(       999) . "\n"; // Mostra "999"
echo "      1000->" . reduz_numero(      1000) . "\n"; // Mostra "1k"
echo "      1001->" . reduz_numero(      1001) . "\n"; // Mostra "1k"
echo "      1499->" . reduz_numero(      1499) . "\n"; // Mostra "1k"
echo "      1500->" . reduz_numero(      1500) . "\n"; // Mostra "2k"
echo "      1501->" . reduz_numero(      1501) . "\n"; // Mostra "2k"
echo "     10000->" . reduz_numero(     10000) . "\n"; // Mostra "10k"
echo "    999499->" . reduz_numero(    999499) . "\n"; // Mostra "999k"
echo "    999500->" . reduz_numero(    999500) . "\n"; // Mostra "1kk"
echo "    999501->" . reduz_numero(    999501) . "\n"; // Mostra "1kk"
echo "1000000000->" . reduz_numero(1000000000) . "\n"; // Mostra "1kkk"
echo "    -77777->" . reduz_numero(    -77777) . "\n"; // Mostra "-78k"
echo "   9499999->" . reduz_numero(   9499999) . "\n"; // Mostra "9kk"
echo "   9500000->" . reduz_numero(   9500000) . "\n"; // Mostra "10kk"
```

[Veja funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/Zxg278)

<sup><sub>EDITADO: Agora também funciona com números negativos. :)</sub></sup>
<sup><sub>EDITADO 2: Bugfix para o 9499999, estava mostrando "10kk" ao invés de "9kk".</sub></sup>

Comment: Se pudesse dava mais um por esse pormenor da recursividade quando tens números negativos :)

Answer (score 3):

Nunca escrevi nada em php, portanto é pouco provável que funcione...

```
function reduz($n) {
    $n=floor($n);
    if ($n      < 1000) return $n;
    if ($n%1000 <  500) return reduz(  $n/1000). "k"
    if ($n%1000 >= 500) return reduz(1+$n/1000). "k";
}
```