# Aparecer 1,0k em vez do número 1000 e assim por diante

Tags: java

Como posso fazer para que apareça em vez de 1000 aparecesse 1,0k e assim por diante?

```
1000 - 1,0k
2000 - 2,0k
10000 - 10,0k
100000 - 100,0k
```

e etc...

```
@Override
    public double getValor(String arg0) {
        Pessoa pessoa = Main.getPessoa();
        double valor = base.configvalor.getConfig().getConfigurationSection(pessoa.getNome()).getDouble("Valor");
        if (base.configvalor.getConfig().getConfigurationSection(pessoa.getNome()).getDouble("Valor") >= 1000) {
            double resultado = Math.ceil(valor/1000.0);
            return (resultado);
        }else {
            return valor;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51047/132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(abreviarComK(1000));
    System.out.println(abreviarComK(2000));
    System.out.println(abreviarComK(10000));
    System.out.println(abreviarComK(300));

  }


  public static String abreviarComK(long numero) {

    if (numero < 1000) {
      return Long.toString(numero);
    } else {
      return (numero/1000.0 + "k").replace(".", ",");
    }

  }

}
```

Não precisa do replace se você for usar ponto no lugar de vírgula.

Veja funcionando no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/5daOki).

Comment: Como posso fazer isso com o metódo: public double ?

Comment: Não entendi. Que método public double? Eu te passei um método que recebe um `long`, que é o que parece bater com a entrada que você tá passando (números sem vírgula). Se quer que esse método receba um double, troque o tipo do parâmetro.

Comment: Coloquei o código que eu tentei, porém não sei como faz para mostrar 1,2k e etc...

Comment: A minha resposta contém a função `abreviarComK` que converte um número para essa representação que você pediu. Basta você chamar a função passando o número e salvar o resultado numa String, assim como está sendo feito ali no `main`. Veja você mesmo funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/5daOki).